# Unable to add multiple values into $_SESSION variable not using keys but only values

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I need to update `$_SESSION['all_product_ids']` with all `produkt_id`values delivered as POST variable via ajax and save them in an array in this session variable.

The problem is that for some reason the value is always overwritten and never added to the current values.

I have this code in my ajax callback function:

```
if( isset( $_POST['product_id'] ) ) { 

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];


    if ( isset ( $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] ) ) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] = [];
    }


    if ( in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['all_product_ids']) ) {
            // do nothing if product id already in the array
    } else {

        $_SESSION['all_product_ids'][] = $product_id;

    }

    echo json_encode( $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] );

}
```

The problem is that the ajax returns always only one (the last clicked/added product id) so the response is `["78"]` or `["60"]` but never `["78", "60"]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964480/storing-multiple-values-in-a-session-variable-with-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964480/storing-multiple-values-in-a-session-variable-with-php)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want array without keys and only values? e.g. `"cat", "dog", "hamster"` instead of `"0" => "cat", "1" => "dog", "2" => "hamster"`? Is it somehow possible via $_SESSION?

Comment: @AhamedZulfan The problem is somewhere else. Because I can easily do `$_SESSION['all_product_ids'] = array('cat', 'dog', 'hamster');` before the last echo json line and I will get the result response in ajax as the array as i want. any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !empty( $_POST['product_id'] ) ) { 

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    if ( isset ( $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] ) ) {
        // do nothing
    } else {

        $_SESSION['all_product_ids'][] .= $product_id;
    }


    if ( in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['all_product_ids']) ) {
            // do nothing if product id already in the array
    } else {

        $_SESSION['all_product_ids'][] .= $product_id;

    }

    echo json_encode( $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] );

}
```

---

**NOTES:**

1 - You need to add `session_start();` at the beginning of the script.
2 - I've changed `isset` to `!empty` otherwise you may get empty values.
3 - Note that `.=` will append to existing array, while `=` will replace whatever is in the array.
4 - I've tested the code on my server and the values are successfully appended to  `$_SESSION['all_product_ids']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// determine if session has started
Function HasSessionStarted() {

    $result = false;

    // Check if session has started
    IF ((session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) || (session_id() == '')) { 
        $result = true; 
    }

    return $result;

}

Function Upd_Product_Session() {

    $sess_products = array();

    IF ( (isset($_POST['product_id'])) && (!empty($_POST['product_id'])) ) {

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id']; // should really do some sanitization and validation

        $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status
        IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }

        IF (isset( $_SESSION['all_product_ids'])) {
            $sess_products = json_decode($_SESSION['all_product_ids'], true); // json decode existing session
        }

        IF (!in_array($product_id, $sess_products) ) { // not in array -> add it
            $sess_products[] = $product_id;
        }

        // Set Session
        $_SESSION['all_product_ids'] = json_encode($sess_products);
        IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }

    }

    // debugging
    die('<pre>'.print_r($sess_products, true).'</pre>');

}
```