# How to add array to session that all array is under one key in session

Tags: php, variables, session, session-variables

I am working on e-commerce shop with clothes and i am pretty new to PHP. I need to create session to store product id, chosen size of product and chosen count of product.

I need to create session like this(if you know what i mean):

```
$_SESSION['cart']['products']['0']['id']
                                 ['size']
                                 ['count]
```

0 interprets auto increment, one product informations for one value to write out in cart.

To use script like this:

```
<?php
$item=array('id'=>$_POST['id'],'size'=>$_POST['size'],'count'=>$_POST['count']);
$_SESSION['cart']['products'][]=$item;
?>
```

I don't know how to explain better, but i need to store 3 informations about chosen product in session.

Foreach i would use in my cart code should look like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['products'] as $key => $val {
        echo $val['id'];
        echo $val['size'];
        echo $val['count'];
```

session_start(); I have as first in document and my forms are correct i think. I would like to have someone help me, Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964480/storing-multiple-values-in-a-session-variable-with-php

Comment: @JulianKoster Ty, i will look there for informations to solve my problem..

Comment: @JulianKoster It's older than 6 years, isn't it outdated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing multiple values in a $\_SESSION variable with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964480/storing-multiple-values-in-a-session-variable-with-php)

Comment: @JaromírMocík it is not outdated.

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing

Comment: @Jaromír Mocík, why not give it a try and then see how superduper not outdated it is? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally will be if you use JSON notation, so

```
$json = '{
   id:'.$_POST['id'].
  ',size:'.$_POST['size'].
  ',count:'.$_POST['count'].
'}';

$_SESSION['cart']['products'][]=$json;
```

and then to access them

```
$item = json_decode( $_SESSION['cart']['products'][0] );
echo $item->id;
echo $item->size;
echo $item->count;
```